# Firebase functions: Custom auth endpoint

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I want to login using custom auth endpoint in firebase admin.
For example using email and password.

```
http://firebasefunctionsaddres.com/loginUsingEmail
```

So from client I want to make request with email and password(and maybe some other info) and on firebase functions side (maybe save some data to firestore) and response with auth token.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I personally didn't use the auth token, because I found an easier approach by using Firestore and just storing the user information there. It is a **very** simple database to use. No queries, it works just like a JavaScript Object!! And encrypt/hash the password of the user by using something like MD5, or SHA 256 **before** storing it!!

Here is a link to the JavaScript Firestore Documentation that'll teach you to store and retrieve data (it works super fast): [Firestore JavaScript Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart)

Also in this way, you have to load less Firebase Resources and all user data is stored in one place! I really like the simplicity of Google Firestore! (In my opinion, soooo much better than PHP and MySQL!)

Comment: I'm already using Firestore and storing user information in firestore collection. My question was how can I add firebase function endpoint so I could update my firestore when user logins.

Comment: @rendom Right, so I'm saying that you can store username and hashed passwords on there, then create your own sign in/register form, and a javascript document that checks for a `sessionStorage` variable that validates login, if not, then it would redirect to login/sign up. It works perfectly on my Firebase website.